# How to get data in single row within facets for data in different elements

Tags: xquery, marklogic, facet

We have data in MarkLogic as follows

```
<article>
<data id=1>
      <author>
        <name>
            <fname>manish</fname>
            <sname>joisar</sname>
       </name>
      </author>
</data>
<data id=2>
      <author>
        <name>
            <fname>Rakesh</fname>
            <sname>Malhotra</sname>
       </name>
      </author>
      <editor>
        <name>
            <fname>manish</fname>
            <sname>joisar</sname>
       </name>
      </editor>
</data>
<data id=3>
      <author>
        <name>
            <fname>manish</fname>
            <sname>joisar</sname>
       </name>
      </author>
      <editor>
        <name>
            <fname>manish</fname>
            <sname>joisar</sname>
       </name>
      </editor>
</data>
</article>
```

Now we have implemented facets as follows

```
<constraint name="AuFacet">
    <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" type="xs:string" facet="{$IsFacet}">
           <element ns="" name="name"/>
           <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
           <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
           <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
    </range>
</constraint>
```

Output comes as follows

```
{
      "name": "authors",
      "type": "xs:string",
      "Values": [
             {
               "value": "manish joisar",
               "count": "2"
              },
             {
               "value": "manish joisar",
               "count": "2"
             },
            {
               "value": "Rakesh Malhotra",
               "count": "1"
            },
         ]
}
```

I want implement data as follows

```
{
      "name": "authors",
      "type": "xs:string",
      "Values": [
            {
               "value": "manish joisar",
               "count": "3"
            }
            {
               "value": "Rakesh Mahotra",
               "count": "1"
            },
     ]
}
```

I do not want to do post processing. As i am only looking for element name, i should get combined count for matching author between Author/editor.
As of now it is counting one document when name found in both & add that in author count but when person is editor, it create separate list with same name.

**Edit**: I have changed data structure, we identified that problem is only when parent element contains sub elements and facet is implemented on parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a range index on an element with substructure creates the value from the entire content of the element as discussed here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_93351

The fact the output has duplicate entries suggests that the indexed values are inconsistent in some way -- possibly in whitespace characters that are normalized in the Search API reporting but not in the index.

One way to look at the values prior to reporting would be to call `cts.countAggregate()` with the equivalent query in QueryConsole:

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.countAggregate

If whitespace or some other inconsistency is the issue, one possible solution would be to concatenate the names in a consistent way as a single atomic value in an attribute and put a range index on that attribute.

An alternative solution might be a field range index that excludes the root:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#id_65763

Another alternative is to create a TDE that constructs either separate columns for the fname and sname (or a single column with the canonicalized and concatenated fname and sname) and groups on the column or columns with a count aggregate.

---

### response to original post

Does it work to configure the query options to count the item (aka value) frequency instead of the fragment (aka document) frequency by adding:

```
<facet-option>item-frequency</facet-option>
```

For more detail, see

- https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_32558
- https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.values

Hoping that helps,

Comment: This does not worked, not sure if MarkLogic has any option to solve this issue, Now we are looking to use xslt to do post processing. If anybody has resolution from MarkLogic itself, then it will be great

Comment: We do have regression tests that apply the item-frequency facet option to range indexes. If the option doesn't work in your case, consider filing a case with MarkLogic Support.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so you mean to say that with item-frequency option, it should work? and should give me the result i mentioned in original question? and does not matter if parents are different ?

Comment: I have modified question, as issue only when facet element contains child element

Comment: It does not worked for field search, it gave result for Manish (1) & Joisar (1), so is there any way index we can create index on combination of multiple sub elements ?

Comment: As noted in the answer, one strategy is to transform the document during write so the name element has an attribute with the canonicalized and concatenated fname and sname. Then, you can add a range index on the attribute. Another alternative is to use a TDE index instead of a range index. I'll add that alternative to the answer.